# Error in exception handler: View [errors.error] not found in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have migrated the laravel project from one server to another server. Both servers are the same configuration but I am getting following error

> Error in exception handler: View [errors.error] not found. in
>   /home/pheonixsolutions/public_html/demo/wmp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/FileViewFinder.php:146

Comment: try running composer update @Karthik_Karthik

Comment: How to update composer

Comment: @karthik karthik Let me google that for you: https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#update

Comment: You need to try with clear cache for config and view

Comment: php artisan cache:clear,
php artisan view:clear,
php artisan route:clear,
php artisan config:cache

Comment: I am getting following error
 php artisan view:clear
[InvalidArgumentException]                               
  There are no commands defined in the "route" namespace.

Comment: php artisan config:cache

                                          
  [InvalidArgumentException]              
  Command "config:cache" is not defined.  
                                          
  Did you mean this?                      
      config:publish

Comment: use `composer update` to update update composer @karthikkarthik

Comment: Check if `errors/error.blade.php` exists @karthikkarthik